# Как повесить событие на тряску телефона используя Python?

Tags: python, kivy

Делаю приложение на Kivy, тут у меня возник вопрос. Можно ли как то повесить событие на тряску телефона? Т.е выполнить какую-нибудь функцию при тряске телефона пользователем. На чем можно такое реализовать используя python?

Answer (score 1):

С библиотекой plyer это реализовать довольно легко.
[Kivy Plyer](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.Gyroscope)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from plyer import gyroscope, vibrator

from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyBox(BoxLayout):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation="vertical", padding=10, spacing=10, **kwargs)       
        self.label = Label(text = '0', font_size = '30sp')
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        gyroscope.enable()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.run_acceleration, 0.1)
        
     
    def run_acceleration(self, *args):
        print(gyroscope.rotation)
        try:
            if (gyroscope.rotation[0] >0.5 or
                gyroscope.rotation[0] < -0.5 or
                gyroscope.rotation[1] > 0.5 or
                gyroscope.rotation[1] < -0.5 or
                gyroscope.rotation[2] > 0.5 or
                gyroscope.rotation[2] < -0.5):
                iter = int(self.label.text)
                self.label.text = str(iter + 1)
                vibrator.vibrate(0.05)
        except:
            pass
    

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()


app = MyApp()
app.run()
```

Comment: Только что протестировал работает не совсем корректно, число изменяется даже если просто наклонить телефон а не при тряске

Comment: Хотя идея с гироскопом мне понравилась, попробую доработать

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать вместо giroskope accelerometer тойже библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Это супер сложно, но реализуемо:

Добавьте в файл buildozer.spec строку с java зависимостями rxjava и rxandroid:

`android.gradle_dependencies =`

дальше нужно изменить build.gradle таким образом:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Потом берём код из этой статьи: https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/304488/

Чуть-чуть корректируем и вставляем в отдельный файл.

Далее опять меняем buildozer.spec и добавляем наш файл java файл:

`android.add_jars = java.jar`

Потом используя библиотеку [pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Мы вызываем методы этого файла и ловим ивент тряски.

**Если у вас получится это сделать выложите репо на гитхаб.**