# Как отследить тряску телефона используя python?

Tags: python, kivy

Есть программа на kivy, как отследить тряску телефона? В kivy такое не видел. Какие есть модули для этого?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как повесить событие на тряску телефона используя Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1319116/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-python)

Comment: Так это мой вопрос, просто я его тогда неправильно сформулировал

Comment: Ну, в kivy есть доступ к гироскопу, значит внимательнее читайте документацию

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что участник многократно задаёт один и тот же вопрос.

Comment: @jediAllen _Так это мой вопрос, просто я его тогда неправильно сформулировал_, а почему вы его не поправили изменив формулировку, а вместо задаёте новый вопос?